# Debug unintended use of memory "belonging" to parent function

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, valgrind

Suppose I have a function `foo` (in C/C++) that is called from a given software tool.

Function `foo` is only allowed to write memory that has been allocated by `foo` or one of the functions called by `foo`, but not to write to memory that has been allocated by the functions that have been executed before calling `foo`.

I have the strong suspicion that at some place `foo` writes to memory it is not allowed to.

Is there a way to systematically debug this behavior? Maybe some fancy flag to valgrind?

Comment: Have you done a basic `valgrind` run? Odds are, if it's writing out of where you want it to write, it'll also be writing over padding and object boundaries.

Comment: @Mahmoud Yep, I did. Basic valgrind does not report any problems - but that may be because of the custom memory management that disturbs valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

The [Valgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.clientreqs) has some Valgrind functions that your program can call.

It looks like `VALGRIND_MAKE_MEM_NOACCESS` may be what you want.

Comment: That's a start. Now I would only need a way to tell valgrind something like 'VALGRIND_MAKE_MEM_NOCACESS_ALL_BUT(memoryblock)` - I do have no idea what memory has been allocated by the parent program, I only know wich memory belongs to my function.

Comment: @Thilo: On Linux you can read and parse the memory map of your process. It's in /proc/$PID/maps and describes the virtual memory layout. Just mark each block (except the stack) and that should do it. You might also be able to get away with marking 0x0 to 0xffffffff but I am not sure what will happen.

Comment: That sounds promising. I will have a try on tuesday (comp time right now ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom allocator ([Boost Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html) comes to mind) to make sure all your memory that you want to 'protect' is contiguously allocated.

Next, set a hardware breakpoint when any data in that memory region is changed.

Comment: Ah, that is what happens if you only give parts of the information. There already is a custom allocator in process. As my function resides within a plugin, I have no way to change the allocation process. Furthermore, I do not have a real way to identify what the calling code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a GDB script that sets a breakpoint on your function, then sets a hardware watch on the memory you suspect is being altered, then continues.

If function `foo` is modifying that memory the hardware watch will trigger on that instruction doing it.

The GDB script might look like:

```
break foo
commands
up
watch array
down
continue
end
```

I didn't test that and it may need tweaking, especially the watch expression. You might be limited to watching only one array element. I believe hardware watchpoints can actually watch only one integer size block: 4 bytes on 32 bit or 8 bytes on 64 bit.

Comment: The problem with that is that I have no idea exactly what memory is modified (out of about 500 MB allocated to the calling programm). Thus, setting a hardware breakpoint would require quite a lot of testing...

Answer (score 0):

The only way foo() can write to the memory outside its scope is if that memory is global, i.e. extern variable, or if foo() had one or more arguments which were meant to be read only but somehow they got modified.

To verify if the calling arguments are getting modified, you can create a structure to hold the arguments and just before returning compare original with saved arguments.

```
struct foo_args {
    int a;
    char *b;
};         

void
foo(int a, char *b) 
{                 
    struct foo_args args;

    args.a = a
    args.b = strdup(b);

    /* The rest of the foo() code. */

    if (args.a != a || strcmp(args.b, b) != 0) {
        printf("error - args got modified\n");
    }    

    free(args.b);
}
```

If the above doesn't catch it, then the likely scenario is that either global, stack or heap memory is getting corrupted.

To have valgrind run the tool may not be practical, in which case you will need to create a 'wrapper' for foo() and ensure using valgrind or something similar that it is not doing what it is not supposed to do.  The other option is to use a debugging library that tracks/monitors memory usage and flags memory errors as they occur.